# Keybord doesn't work in Nautilus (and gnome-terminal) after ubuntu update from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, nautilus, keyboard

When i open any folder, window of Nautilus appears, and i can't use keybord keys (i've tried TAB,F2,F3,F9,CTRL+L,ARROWS,DEL), except ALT+F4.

And in gnome-terminal i can't type at all. I tried to open it using: CTRL+ALT+T and ALT+F2 gnome-terminal, terminal opens but keybord in terminal doesn't work, even CTRL+D, ALT+F4 works.

Comment: Did the keyboard work in the login screen? Can you try using the terminal outside the GUI - Ctrl-Alt-F1 will take you there and Ctrl-Alt-F7 will take you back to the graphical environment.

Comment: In login screen keybord works, it works in firefox, works when i press Super key (to show main menu), works when ALT+F2, it works in other terminals(CTRL+ALT+1). But it doesn't work when i click on desktop icon and try to use ARROWS or DEL or F2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved. 
GXNeur was the problem maker. 
I removed it from autostart, and after ubuntu restarting keybord works fine.